# ODI 12c Data Lineage Query

Tags: oracle

can I please get ODI 12c Data Lineage Query in SQL language for Source table, staging table, target table details in the given mapping?

Please provide the Query
I need sql/oracle query with snp tables.
I have multiple mappings to look into.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: when I am getting source columns in output, then target columns are nulls. when I am getting target columns in output, then source columns are nulls. But I need both source,  target columns and which source column is related to which target column in single row. I will post my data lineage query in 3 different parts. can U please look into it.

Comment: Part1 :
SELECT m.name AS mapping_name, t1.table_name AS source_tables, src_col.col_name AS source_columns, t2.table_name AS target_tables, tgt_col.col_name AS target_columns 
FROM  dnogp2_bia_odirepo.snp_mapping m INNER JOIN dnogp2_bia_odirepo.snp_map_comp mc ON m.i_mapping = mc.i_owner_mapping INNER JOIN dnogp2_bia_odirepo.snp_map_cp   cp ON mc.i_map_comp = cp.i_owner_map_comp INNER JOIN dnogp2_bia_odirepo.snp_map_ref  mr ON mc.i_map_ref = mr.i_map_ref

Comment: Part2:  LEFT JOIN dnogp2_bia_odirepo.snp_table t1 ON mr.i_ref_id = t1.i_table AND t1.table_type = 'SY'
 LEFT JOIN dnogp2_bia_odirepo.snp_table t2 ON mr.i_ref_id = t2.i_table AND t2.table_type = 'T'
 LEFT JOIN dnogp2_bia_odirepo.snp_col src_col ON t1.i_table = src_col.i_table

Comment: Part3:  LEFT JOIN dnogp2_bia_odirepo.snp_col tgt_col ON t2.i_table = tgt_col.i_table
WHERE cp.direction = 'I' --Input connection point AND cp.i_map_cp NOT IN (
 SELECT i_start_map_cp FROM dnogp2_bia_odirepo.snp_map_conn)